# Why examples don't work? (a struggle with imports)

Tags: openlayers

On the page https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html I copied the HTML code from under the map to `/tmp/a.html` and run `firefox /tmp/a.html`.

At first two problems appeared easy to fix:

1. SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
2. The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document...

To fix it:

1. replace `<script>` by `<script type="module">`
2. add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` into `<head></head>`

But what to do with the third error?

`TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: ol/Map.js`

I have Firefox 60.0.1.

So, are the HTML codes in the examples meant to be used as I did, or did I misunderstand something?

And what do I need in my code to `import Map from ol/Map.js`?

(I tried to reformulate the question, but if I still deserve a negative ranking, please explain why. Thanks)

Comment: ive got the same error trying to help you, this page may not be changed since the update, normally the examples work very well with copy paste

Comment: I am also trying to use ol es6 modules directly in the browser. I only have a partial answer. To `import Map from ol/Map.js` use a relative or fully qualified path to your ol modules. e.g.  `import Map from './node_modules/ol/Map.js';` After doing that I had to edit several ol modes and provide a relative path to node_modules/rbush/rbush.js. Unfortunately I'm still getting errors related to importing rbush.

Answer (score 15):

It's because there are some changes due to latest release of OpenLayers (V5.0).
Now samples are based on ES6 modules whereas there was before another way of doing

You can compare [the "simple" v4.6.5 sample](http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/simple.html) with ["simple" master sample](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/simple.html)

Using `<script type="module">` is not enough as it does not solve dependencies when doing `import Map from ol/Map.js`

There are at least 3 ways of doing:

1. The usual way to create Openlayers sample using version 5.0.0 is using à bundler like Webpack or Parcel. There is [a tutorial for this](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html).
2. I've also investigated JSPM with [this sample](https://twitter.com/ThomasG77/status/995845395736653829)
3. You can always use the old way of doing, like in version 4.6.5 using [this other official tutorial](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) without using `import`.

For solution 1, you can use codesandbox.io to avoid setting a local parcel/webpack environment like illustrated with [this tweet](https://twitter.com/openlayers/status/924003219293925376).

I know there is a work on progress to refactor the code for samples and I also submitted some suggestions for codesandbox.io e.g https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8324

Comment: I have a similar issue in that I have an OpenLayers4 based program with a class that extends ol.Tile.  With OpenLayers6, ol.Tile doesn't exist in the ol object.  Any suggestions on how to deal with that?

Answer (score 11):

had the same problem. openlayers is outstanding, v5 examples are not :(

e.g.https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html

my fix for v5(.3.0) examples:

```
    <!-- ADD build-REFERENCE for v5(.3.0) // github.com/openlayers/openlayers/ -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

    <script>
    // CONVERT imports to var
    var Map                 = ol.Map;        //~ import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
    var View                = ol.View;       //~ import View from 'ol/View.js';
    var {easeIn, easeOut}   = ol.easing;     //~ import {easeIn, easeOut} from 'ol/easing.js';
    var TileLayer           = ol.layer.Tile; //~ import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
    var {fromLonLat}        = ol.proj;       //~ import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj.js';
    var OSM                 = ol.source.OSM; //~ import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';        
    // ...
```

process: use "copy" on example page, "paste" to new html file. modify like above. run in firefox.

Comment: thanks a lot, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549364/903783 too for some more cases like import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js' and how to convert those too (maybe there's a better way, improvised a bit there)

Answer (score 4):

based on lou's answer, here's a fix I just did for the [Marker animation example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html):

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Marker Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<label for="speed">
  speed:&nbsp;
  <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
</label>

<button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>

<script>
  var Feature = ol.Feature; //import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
  //var Map = ol.Map; //import Map from 'ol/Map.js'; //commented-out, use ol.Map in code instead of Map, internal JS Map object causes conflicts in newer browsers
  var View = ol.View; //import View from 'ol/View.js';
  var Polyline = ol.format.Polyline; //import Polyline from 'ol/format/Polyline.js';
  var Point = ol.geom.Point; //import Point from 'ol/geom/Point.js';
  var {Tile, Vector} = ol.layer; //import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
  var TileLayer = Tile;
  var VectorLayer = Vector;

  //var BingMaps = ol.source.BingMaps; //import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps.js';

  var VectorSource = ol.source.Vector; //import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';
  var {Circle, Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style} = ol.style; //import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
  var CircleStyle = Circle;

  // This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
  // It is usually loaded with AJAX.
  var polyline = [ ...
```

and to use an [ESRI sattelite map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316988/how-can-i-add-satellite-map-in-openlayers-5) or [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) (plain) map instead of [Bing Maps](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/) one (which requires a key), do this extra edit to the Marker animation example:

```
  var map = new ol.Map({ //don't do new Map(...) here, uses some internal JS Map object in newer browsers
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: new View({
      center: center,
      zoom: 10,
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 19
    }),
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source:
            //new ol.source.OSM()
        
            new ol.source.XYZ({
              attributions: ['Powered by Esri',
                             'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
              attributionsCollapsible: false,
              url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
              maxZoom: 23
            })

            /*
            new BingMaps({
              imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels',
              key: 'Your Bing Maps Key from http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ here'
            })
            */
      }),
      vectorLayer
    ]
  });
```

Comment: vectorLayer - how did you create (new) this object?

Comment: var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker]
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
          /*hide geoMarker if animation is active*/
          if (animating && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
            return null;
          }
          return styles[feature.get('type')];
        }
      });

Comment: Beware of the "new Map" I had used there, doesn't seem to work in latest browsers where there's a built-in Map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object. You need to do     map = new ol.Map instead and remove the var Map = ol.Map at the start (will update the sample)

Comment: Thanks again for hinting about the map object.

Answer (score 1):

```
The example doesn't work because of you maybe just copy past data from page and not look to DOC menu item
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html
So step by step:
1. npm init (here u set your index.js as an entry point)
2. npm install ol (it adds OpenLayer to your application)
3. npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler
4. npm start (it run a web server on localhost:1234 and you will see your example working fine
If needed, then
5. npm build (it create /dist folder which you needed a copy to your web server, inside it will be converted js file.
```