# Openlayers Examples: how to use them?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

The OpenLayers community provides many great examples on this page: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/index.html

On each example there is a copy button to copy the code. But in this copied code they have imports like:

```js
import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import Polyline from 'ol/format/Polyline.js';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Icon, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
```

Sorry for the maybe stupid question:

Where do I get this `*.js` files from?

How can I get quickly the examples to run on my local machine?

Comment: Did you read this?  http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

Comment: yes i advice to read the tutorial and come back when your stuck.

Comment: I've already made a summary at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093964/why-examples-dont-work-a-struggle-with-imports/51110511#51110511

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. @Archer: you're link to the doc/tutorials/bundle helped me a lot, and I found as well https://github.com/openlayers/ol-parcel and https://github.com/openlayers/ol-webpack. On my Mac with node v8.9.4 and npm 6.1.0 is after npm install only a package-lock.json available, no package.json. It seems to me that for new node/npm versions the doc/tutorials/bundle needs maybe an update? But it helped me a lot and I got it with the package.json from github.

Comment: @ThomasGratier: the codesandbox.io sample from your tweet https://twitter.com/openlayers/status/924003219293925376 looks really interesting to me. Great!

Comment: PS: it's not my tweet :) but one of the OpenLayers official Twitter account. I was just referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install npm : https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm,
2. Check after installation, from command prompt run : `node -v`
3. run : `npm -v`
4. Make sure that you have last update npm , from command prompt run: `npm install npm@latest -g`
5. Create a new project folder
6. From command prompt: `cd` to the new project created in  nr. 5

- To create `package.json` in your project folder ,run: `npm init`. I just leave the default value for first, you could always edit the file after that
- run : `npm install ol`
- run : `npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler`
- edit `package.json`, create `index.js` and `index.html` as shown in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html
- run : `npm start`

Result in: http://localhost:1234/

Answer (score 1):

After the helpful hints here I found as well helpful documentation in npm docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol with ol examples on github for using webpack https://github.com/openlayers/ol-webpack or using  parcel https://github.com/openlayers/ol-parcel.

Answer (score 0):

All these *.js file are define in ol package. Here is a link for all classes and namespace defined in ol package.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html